# Hot Completable with long running tasks

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

By default `Completable` is not hot. But I have case where hot Completable would be really useful: downloading and caching set of large files:

```
class DownloadManager {
  Completable downloadAndCacheA();
  Completable downloadAndCacheB();
}

Completable.merge(
  downloadManager.downloadAndCacheA(),
  downloadManager.downloadAndCacheB()
).subscribe();
```

When files are large user can leave the app and turn back. So client code can unsubscribe from these completables and subscribe again. One file can be downloaded, but another is still in progress. But as `Completable` is not hot downloading starts again.

Possible options is to:

- Make [hot Completable](http://akarnokd.blogspot.nl/2015/12/the-new-completable-api-part-2-final.html).
- Use hot Observable which returns `Object`.
- Use just `Thread` instance with custom `Completable` which interact with each other.

Don't really like all these solutions because of different reasons. Is there better way to support long running completable tasks?

Comment: Have you looked at [Completable.cache](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#cache()) and [CompletableSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/CompletableSubject.html).

Comment: @akarnokd thanks! Tried cache but probably in a different way. Will look at cache and CompletableSubject again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [cache](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#cache()), suggested by akarnokd, is probably the easiest way.

```
public Completable downloadAndCache() {
   if (completable == null) {
          completable = Completable.fromAction(this::syncDownloadAndCache)
                                   .cache();
   }
   return completable;
}
```